# How to update last n records from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have query like this:

I want to update last 50 records from my table

So I wrote a query like this

```
update transaction_tbl 
set dtime = '2014-04-16 14:15:47.243'
where transactid in (select  top (50)  from transaction_tbl order by transactid  desc)
```

while executing this I get this error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'

What is wrong with my query? How can I resolve this issue?

I am working with SQL Server 2008. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: select  top (50)  from transaction_tbl order by transactid  desc, the transactid  should be after the order by clause.

Comment: that time also getting same error

Comment: you forgot to write column name in sub query!

Comment: select top (50) * from transaction_tbl order by transactid desc

Comment: where i have to add column name in sub query

Comment: after -> top(50) transactid  from ...

Comment: i have to give there updated column name?

Comment: Yes , You have provide column name!   
i am not able to post answer !! is there any issue with Stackoverflow ??

Comment: your query worked fine for me,,thank for your help

Comment: make my comment up vote for your help !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the column name to the subquery:

```
update transaction_tbl set dtime='2014-04-16 14:15:47.243'
  where transactid in (select top (50) transactid from transaction_tbl order by transactid desc)
```